# grails session expire after one year and redirect to user login with out spring securitry

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to do a user login that will stop after one year i.e. 365 days

where do I need to set the code? grails 2.4.4**

note: Not using spring security core plugin!

Comment: What are you using for authentication?  Are you using some other plugin, or writing your own?

Comment: `def authenticate = { def user = User.findByUsernameAndPassword(params.username,params.password) if(user){ session.user=user.username if(session.user=="sai"){ redirect(action:"adminDashboard") } else{ redirect(action:"userDashboard") } } else{ flash.message = "sorry, ${params.username}. please try again" redirect(action:"login1") } }`  @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using spring security, then the most logical place would be in a filter, which if you upgrade to Grails 3 will become an interceptor:
https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#filters

Although I would question why your not using spring security? The core plugin is quite good, and does a few things, that if you were to roll your own, you would probably miss.

Comment: Would it be better to configure session expiration in the container?

Comment: Hmm looking at it again I think what he wanted was an account expiration, not at session expiration. A one year session, would be pretty long... Although I didn't think about setting the container expiration, at the time.

Comment: Right.  I had overlooked the question wanted a 1 year expiration.  I think you are correct.  The question doesn't really make sense either way, but I think your interpretation makes more sense.

Comment: am new to grails and its my first task , i heard about core plugin but need to do task with out plugin will you help !! @virtualdogbert

Comment: Don't worry about being new. Read the link I posted, and that will give you the setup for a filter. In the filter, you will have to get the current user, and lookup the expiration. Based on the expiration you can redirect to an expired account page. How you get the current user without spring security, I don't know. I would talk to someone on your team, to find out what you are using for security. Depending on what you're using, it may make sense to push for an upgrade to spring security, but that depends on your app.